# JAXBException when marshalling a class with JPA annotations

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, jaxb

I got the following exception when marshalling Comment objects to JSON:

> javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class javax.jdo.identity.LongIdentity
>   nor any of its super class is known to this context.  at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getBeanInfo(JAXBContextImpl.java:594)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:648)

Below is my Comment definition, note that I mixed JAXB annotations (for marshalling) and JPA ones (for persistence with GAE).

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "Comment")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @XmlElement(name = "CommentId")
    private Long commentId;

    @Basic
    @XmlElement(name = "Author")
    private String author;

...
}
```

What I don't get is why the exception has something to do with LongIdentity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try annotating the properties instead of the fields.  The JPA implementation may have used byte code manipulation to add a field of type LongIdentity.

Comment: Additional information, this exception happened only after I persisted a new comment instance to GAE and JAXB tried to marshall the persisted comment to JSON.
Everything is ok when I retreive comments out of repository and marshall to JSON.

Comment: Did you try putting the annotations on the property instead of the field?

Comment: Hi Blaise, yes I did. But I failed to commit transaction this time, got org.datanucleus.transaction.NucleusTransactionException: Transaction failed to commit. BTW, I moved the annotations to getCommentId().

Answer (score 2):

Blaise really shed light on my question, the problem solved and here is the modified Comment class.

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "Comment")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Comment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @XmlElement(name = "CommentId")
    public Long getCommentId();

    @Basic
    @XmlElement(name = "Author")
    public String getAuthor();

...
}
```